# Not able to fetch large amount of data through recv() pipe in multiprocessing in Python in lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, pipe

I have implemented multiprocessing in python using pipe() in lambda fucntion.

I am not able to receive API response in one variable using recv() function.

I tried small amount of data, it is working fine but if it is large amount of data it is showing me lambda timeout error at that point only.

Can anyone help me for questions ?

1. What is max size of bytes we can receive through recv in pipe.
2. Can we define timeout seconds in pipe()
3. How to fetch large amount of data in (mb) in pipe in multiprocessing in python.
4. What is other multiprocessing method which can handle large amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `multiprocessing.Pipe` instance you are returned two `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` instances. According to the documentation on connections:

> **send_bytes**(*buffer*[, *offset*[, *size*]])
> Send byte data from a bytes-like object as a complete message.
>
> If *offset* is given then data is read from that position in buffer. If size is given then that many bytes will be read from buffer. Very large buffers (approximately 32 MiB+, though it depends on the OS) may raise a `ValueError` exception

So the maximum size is platform-dependent. There is also no timeout specification you can use. But even if you attempt to send something smaller than the platform's maximum send size through one of the connection pairs, **the sender might block after having sent some portion of the data unless there is another thread or process concurrently reading the pipe via the other connection**. Think of the pipe as having a buffer of limited size that is being filled by the sender and emptied by the receiver. If there is no thread emptying the buffer, then the sender will block once the buffer is completely filled. On my Windows system the following will cause the application to block and never terminate:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe

recv_conn, send_conn = Pipe(False)  # not full duplex
send_conn.send_bytes(b'1' * 2_000_000)
...  # We never arrive here
```

However, there is no such problem with the following code where we have a thread emptying the pipe:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe
from threading import Thread

def worker(conn):
    data = conn.recv_bytes()
    print(len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recv_conn, send_conn = Pipe()
    p = Thread(target=worker, args=(recv_conn,))
    p.start()
    N_BYTES = 2_000_000
    send_conn.send_bytes(b'1' * N_BYTES)
    p.join()
    print('Done')
```

Prints:

```None
2000000
Done
```

If you use a `multiprocessing.Queue` you will not hang with the following:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue

q = Queue()
q.put('1' * 2_000_000)
```

A `multiprocessing.Queue` is implemented with a `multiprocessing.Pipe` *and* a thread. When the call to `q.put()` is made, the data is placed in a local, unlimited size "buffer" (I believe a `collections.deque` instance) and it is a thread that has been started as part of the queue's implementation that takes this data and sends it to the pipe's connection. If there is no other thread calling `get` on the queue instance, the thread that is writing to the pipe will indeed hang, but the main thread continues running.

Comment: Does this not answer question? If not, what is missing?